# developing cytospace.js extensions in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cytoscape.js

I want to develop a [Cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) extension using [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). I used [slush cytoscape extension](https://github.com/cytoscape/slush-cytoscape-extension) at the start. But I want to use [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) to keep things tidy. I can use `tsc` and convert my `ts` code to `js`. But what happens if there are multiple folders etc.. ? Is there a better way?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what problem your trying to explain,  tsc just compiles typescript to js, were does multiple folders come into play here?

Comment: actually I just recognize that using typescript compiler (tsc) is pretty convenient for now. If you have dependencies, it automatically detects them and converts them too. I think I can go with that